# How to show a progress bar for a layout until the SmartImageView is loaded

Tags: java, android, load, internalsvisibleto

How can I trigger `spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);` after `SmartImageView` is loaded?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    mUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra(URL);
    Image = (SmartImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivP);
    final ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loading);
    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Image.setImageUrl(mUrl);
    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can  have `OnCompleteListener()` on smartImageView

So use it like this.

```
// start the progress dialog

    smartImageView.setImageUrl("Your image url", new OnCompleteListener() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    // end the progress dialog

                }
            });
```

Comment: hi, think you , i try it before , but I could not do it. can you please write all code ? ^_^

Comment: Has anyone found out how to do this yet? There doesn't seem to be a handler. Doesn't seem to have the option at add this in the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with SmartImageView, but what you probably want is to set a place holder image into the `SmartImageView` and then replace it after the image is done downloading. alternately you want to display a loading view over the imageView while you download the image, and get a listener that will let you know when it's done downloading.

Take a look at the [Picasso library](https://github.com/square/picasso) as it does exactly that and it is extremely easy to use (1 line) and lets you define a placeholder image, error image, fade animation, and listener to have custom actions based on download result.